# Setting up a relational database with drupal

Tags: mysql, database, drupal

I've Always used my sql and php to code website for my school project.
Now, for a real project they told me to do an ecommerce website, but that doesn't need to have price.
It just need to show product, and technical references of the product. with some more relation. i've set up a entity relationship scheme that include subtable for description in every Language.

I know drupal is a CMS and is based on a database. I can link it to my database? with my relationship entity? Or drupal work with his own database, so i need to create relationship between entity on drupal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal makes it own DB. You can create relationships between entities within Drupal.

Checkout the [Entity reference module](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference).